# Can I write on iPad using touch typing technique?

Tags: ipad, text-input

Is there any way on iPad that I can write text on iPad using [Touch Typing technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing), as this is the way I use keyboard?

Comment: You don't need to, the iPad's 9.7" screen is small enough, so you can see both the content and the keyboard at the same time without being distracted. I personally touch type on keyboard, but feel comfortable not touch typing on iPad. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The onscreen iPad keyboard offers no way to (re)orient your fingers to the home keys, which makes touch typing nearly impossible in my experience. However, with practice many iPad owners become skilled at using the onscreen keyboard well.

If you absolutely need to touch type longer documents, you can [use a bluetooth keyboard](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4111) with the iPad.

I rarely carry the external keyboard when I'm out and about, but if I plan to settle in to write I toss it in my bag and when traveling I keep one in my hotel room for evening writing marathons.

Comment: I touch type and while I've gotten faster with the iPad keypad, it's too small for me, even if the key layout and shift keys acted like their physical keyboard counterparts. I think your answer is spot on: get faster with whatever works on these on screen keypads and use a "real" keyboard for heavy lifting. Some folks are faster with their thumbs than they are with the iPad keyboard as it is and as many know, the iPad keyboard can be split for "thumbing." I don't do this but I've seen many heavy textures doing it.